# Forced Async operation in a (event like) method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a piece of code that I am not feeling comfortable.

- I don't want to block the UI
- Read operation works synchronously (reading may broke [50 ms rule](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html))
- Save operation supports async (returns `Task`)
- I have to await `SaveChanges` (so operation could be completed before `Dispose`)

```
public Task AddToMyProject(string directory) {
    return Task.Run(async () => {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory)) return;

        using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateContext()) {
            var existing = context.WatchDirectories.FirstOrDefault(wd => wd.Directory == directory);
            if (existing == null) {
                var childWatchers = context.WatchDirectories.Where(wd => wd.Directory.StartsWith(directory));
                foreach (var watchDirectory in childWatchers) {
                    context.Delete(watchDirectory);
                    RemoveDirectoryWatcher(watchDirectory.Directory);
                }

                context.Insert(new WatchDirectory { Directory = directory });
                await context.SaveChanges()
                    .ContinueWith(t => AddDirectoryWatcher(directory));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I just want to know if there is a better approach for this.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `WatchDirectories.FirstOrDefault` you can make use of `Any()` which is more meaningful.

Also if you are checking `Any()` you can return early and save horizontal spacing.

```
public Task AddDirectoryWatcher(string directory) {
    return Task.Run(async () => {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory)) return;

        using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateContext()) {
            if (context.WatchDirectories.Any(wd => wd.Directory == directory)) { return; };

            var childWatchers = context.WatchDirectories.Where(wd => wd.Directory.StartsWith(directory));
```

---

This `AddDirectoryWatcher()` is using a `context` to delete and insert items. Doesn't the `RemoveDirectoryWatcher()` method already uses a `context` too ? If yes, the call to `context.Delete(watchDirectory);` is redundant.

---

Instead of checking if the passed directory exists and silently returning , I would check this before calling the method and throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Comment: My real concerns were [pitfalls of async lambda](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx) and [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html). 
But you are right about .Any usage, there used to be an UpdateTime property which is updated every time an object saved, I removed it but forgot to change the code, thanks.
By the way, AddDirectoryWatcher and RemoveDirectoryWatcher are not using context, they just create/remove FileSystemWatcher objects.

Comment: I realized my code looks recursive, my mistake. I changed the method's name in the post, because it contained top secret information :) I fixed it now.

Comment: Hi @UmutOzel, if you liked this answer then maybe you can reward the poster with an upvote + accept

Comment: Hi @janos, sorry but this answer does not answer my questions about async/await usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
await context.SaveChanges()
    .ContinueWith(t => AddDirectoryWatcher(directory));
```

This means that when `SaveChanges()` throws an exception, you're going to silently ignore it. Generally speaking, you shouldn't use `ContinueWith()` when you can use `await`:

```
await context.SaveChanges();
AddDirectoryWatcher(directory);
```